# Rspec giving databasecleaner problems in a custom folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have opened a folder spec/features. When I launch `rspec spec/` everything goes well, but if I do `rspec spec/features` I get:

An error occurred in a `before(:suite)` hook.
Failure/Error: DatabaseCleaner[:active_record].strategy = :transaction

```
NameError:
  uninitialized constant DatabaseCleaner
# ./spec/spec_helper.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

what could  be happening?